# Set recurrence transaction for every one minute on Unzer payment gateway

Tags: payment

I need to set recurrence payment for every one minute with the XML direct debit method on Unzer.

Anyone can let me know the correct XML or expression for it?

```
<Execution>
<Minute>*</Minute>
<Second>00</Second>
</Execution>
```

Above is the current execution XML that I have been set. But that is not working correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is answer.

```
<Execution>
<Expression>0 3 * * * ?</Expression>
</Execution>
```